# Several mode to write the symbol of a vector

Tags: math-mode, symbols, books, mathtools, mtpro

When I use the command `\overrightarrow{...}` I observe that the space between the two lines increases due to the presence of this command. I often use the command `\widebar{...}`, `\bar{...}` or `\overbar{...}`. I don't like the symbol `\vec{...}` because the arrow is inclined.

In a university textbook in English that I use are used the classic vector symbols both in bold and without bold. Obviously the space between the two lines seems to be the same and it does not increase.

Two images from my textbook:

[image]

[image]

There are two questions:

1) *If I were to use for the vector symbols complete with `mtpro2` could I have vectors both in bold and those without bold?*

2) *Is there a possibility of not increasing the space between lines when using the vectors like English textbook images?*

Here there is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\noindent 
$\overrightarrow{d}$, $\overrightarrow{a}$, \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

You can also see in the red rectangle that the arrow overlaps the character.

Comment: The `halloweenmath` package offers you the `\overscriptrightarrow` command, which uses a smaller arrows that fits more comfortably between the lines.

Comment: Any correct answer is always welcome for me.

Comment: I vaguely remembered having answered a similar question some time ago, and I didn’t want to post a duplicate answer: albeit it is not exactly the same question, have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359519/69818) of mine.

Comment: I copied your MWE, added `\usepackage{halloweenmath}`, replaced `\overrightarrow` with `\overscriptrightarrow`, and the extra space between the lines disappeared (confirmed with `\showlists`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `esvect` package, which defines 8 possible arrow tips that you choose through an option:

[image]

Here is the result with the default (option `d`):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}
    \usepackage{esvect}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent
    \lipsum[1]
    \noindent
    $\vv{d}$, $\vv{a}$, \lipsum[2]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice :-):-)  I didn't know about this package. But does using the `mtpro2[lite]` package change the style of the vectors provided by `esvect` and possibly improve them?

Comment: I don't think so, since it uses its own font via an own command. However, as I don't have mtpro2 installed, I cannot test it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand\myVec[1]{\savebox\mybox{\hbox{\ensuremath{\overrightarrow{#1}}}}\ensuremath{\overrightarrow{#1}}{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+3pt}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent$\myVec{f}\bm{\myVec{a}}$\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I can't really understand the "possibility of not increasing the line's spacing" and also don't let the arrows overlap the previous line... because for exapmle in your textbooks the technology could be so old that they was just added after the actual text and the author had created/changed his wording in order to not leave an arrow below a character that needs space below the "baseline".

Comment: My theory about votes has been and will always be to vote positively for those who dedicate their time to others. +1. You can see in my profile the high number of votes.

Comment: @Sebastiano ... I use this way too... Not always but in many cases... The bad thing with this kind of upvoting, is that you actually don't really help the next visitors to find the more appropriate/best answer and this is not really good. (But sometimes I can't not upvote too... even about the effort even about the usefulness of the answer even to give a new user the right to comment in posts instead of answering on it because has no the right to comment etc)

Comment: Obviously the answer has to be good if it wasn't good I wouldn't have voted for it. I agree with you.

Comment: Thanks... (Just said that because sometimes on answers in my posts, I prefer one, but almost always have voted for all of them... and it feels strange that could not add a second vote to the better to show to the people that it is actually better... But this happens mostly in my posts or in posts I have particiapated -that also upvoting often-). Goodnight from me!