# Categorical limits with smaller arrows

Tags: spacing, amsmath, arrows, xrightarrow

I have always disliked the `amsmath` commands `\varinjlim` and `\varprojlim` for categorical limits. The arrows are too big and dominating, and the whole things take up too much vertical space, messing up the line spacing. I therefore usually define my own commands, see below, and would like to know if they can be improved and made more robust? In the current form, they use `\raisebox` which uses absolute dimensions and therefore causes issues when used e.g. in an index (see picture below). How can my construction be improved?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126081/underarrow-with-smaller-depth-shorter-minimum-length-and-smaller-arrow-head) has some interesting solutions, but one uses PGF, which seems like extreme overkill to me, and the second one does not scale properly when used e.g. in indices. Oh yes, and there is a package called `halloweenmath`, but I’m not sure I trust a package with such a name. I think I prefer a solution by some TeX guru in here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\dirlimformat[1]{
    \mathop{
        \smash{
            \operatorname*{#1}\limits_{
                {}
                \raisebox{.21em}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{.85}{$\m@th
                    \xrightarrow{%
                        \hphantom
                        {%
                            \!\!
                            \scalebox{1.17}{$\m@th
                                {\operatorname{#1}}
                            $}
                            \!\!
                        }
                    }
                $}}
            }
        }
        \vphantom{\textstyle\lim_n}
    }
}

\newcommand\invlimformat[1]{
    \mathop{
        \smash{
            \operatorname*{#1}\limits_{
                {}
                \raisebox{.21em}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{.85}{$\m@th
                    \xleftarrow{%
                        \hphantom
                        {%
                            \!\!
                            \scalebox{1.17}{$\m@th
                                {\operatorname{#1}}
                            $}
                            \!\!
                        }
                    }
                $}}
            }
        }
        \vphantom{\textstyle\lim_n}
    }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\dirlim{\dirlimformat{lim}}
\newcommand\invlim{\invlimformat{lim}}

\begin{document}

\( \varinjlim X_n \) vs.\ \( \dirlim X_n \)

\( \varprojlim X_n \) vs.\ \( \invlim X_n \)

\( a^{\invlim X_n} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the [old-arrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/old-arrows) package? It generates much smaller arrowheads.

Comment: @Mico No, but it seems very much focused on Computer Modern, which is a font I avoid my all means (except when creating MWEs on TeX.SX).

Comment: Why do you claim that the `old-arrows` package is "very much focused on Computer Modern"? That's decidedly not the case. It works fine with newtxmath,  mtpro2, txfonts, mathptmx, newpxmath, pxfonts, mathpazo, and likely many more math font packages too.

Comment: @Mico I just read the abstract and got that impression. Maybe I was wrong. Meanwhile, the old arrows were so much prettier. The standard CM arrows are disgusting to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions of `\varinjim` and `\varptojlim` in `amsopn.sty` are

```
\def\varinjlim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}
\def\varprojlim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\leftarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}
```

The arrows are thus always in `\textstyle`. You can make your own definitions (or change the default ones---with the usual caveats) using `\scriptstyle`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\dirlim{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\rightarrowfill@\scriptstyle}}\nmlimits@}
\newcommand\invlim{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\leftarrowfill@\scriptstyle}}\nmlimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parskip=\medskipamount

\( \varinjlim X_n \) vs.\ \( \dirlim X_n \)

\( \varprojlim X_n \) vs.\ \( \invlim X_n \)

\( a^{\varprojlim X_n} \) vs.\ \( a^{\invlim X_n} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course this will be sub-optimal in `\scriptscriptstyle`; you could add a `\mathpalette` workaround which looks slightly less bad

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

% same as above
\newcommand\dirlimA{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\rightarrowfill@\scriptstyle}}\nmlimits@}
\newcommand\invlimA{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\leftarrowfill@\scriptstyle}}\nmlimits@}

% alternative version
\def\varlim@@#1#2{%
  \vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
    \hfil$#1\operator@font lim$\hfil\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}
    \expandafter#2\ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\newcommand\dirlimB{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@@\rightarrowfill@}\nmlimits@}
\newcommand\invlimB{\mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@@\leftarrowfill@}\nmlimits@}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parskip=\medskipamount

$\varinjlim_{\varinjlim_{\varinjlim}}$

$\dirlimA_{\dirlimA_{\dirlimA}}$

$\dirlimB_{\dirlimB_{\dirlimB}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually think the scriptscriptstyle `\dirlimB` has a bit too much spacing between the arrow and the `lim`. But that could of course be a result of the reduced height of the math font in scriptscriptstyle.

Comment: @Gaussler I see what you mean, but this is a 600% magnification screenshot. Imagine it printed at real size. On the other hand, in the present code said vertical spacing is given in terms of `\ex@`. Since we are already in a `\mathpalette` we could easily add something which scales with the current math style.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `old-arrows`. With the option `old`, the standard arrows are not modified, but we can patch `\varinjlim` and `\varprojlim` to use the smaller arrow tips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\varinjlim}{\rightarrowfill@}{\varrightarrowfill@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojlim}{\leftarrowfill@}{\varleftarrowfill@}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\rightarrow\varrightarrow\varinjlim_{x\in X} \quad \varprojlim_{x\in X}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With even smaller arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\varinjlim}{\rightarrowfill@}{\varrightarrowfill@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varinjlim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojlim}{\leftarrowfill@}{\varleftarrowfill@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojlim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjlim_{x\in X} \quad \varprojlim_{x\in X}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two questions: (a) How will this compare in practise to @campa‘s solution? (b) How do you most easily replicate this directly, without loading `old-arrows`?

Comment: @Gaussler The arrows are different. That's all.

Comment: As much as I like the output, I don’t quite feel comfortable about using a package whose main purpose is to return a part of TeX to its 1992 version. That feels like relying on the `tabu` package or some LaTeX 2.09-era solution.

Comment: @Gaussler No, it's a completely different matter; the `old-arrows` package provides additional glyphs (if called with the `old` option). It's a well written package fully compatible with the current LaTeX kernel. The glyphs *happen* to be the pre-1992 version of the arrows (which are much better than the post-1992 arrows, IMHO).