# Creating a variant of \varinjlim without redefining \varinjlim itself

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I would like to define a command `\laxcolim` which renders the same as `\varinjlim` does, except with two "l"'s instead of one. But I still want the usual `\varinjlim` command to be available to me. (Similarly, I want a command `\laxlim` which is like `\varprojlim` but with an extra "l".)

I tried modifying [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342041/12246) to the following:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools}

\makeatletter\def\varlim@#1#2{%
\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
\hfil$#1\operator@font llim$\hfil\cr
\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#2\cr
\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \varinjlim( E_{α},f_{α\,β}),\quad\varprojlim( E_{α},f_{β\,α}),\]%

\end{document}​
```

The result looks great except that it changes the `\varinjlim` command itself, whereas I need both the usual `\varinjlim` command and my modified one to be available to me.

To address this issue, I made the following changes. I don't actually know what I'm doing, but the intention is to define a new command `\varllim` rather than overwriting the `\varlim` command, and then to copy the usual definition of `\varinjlim`, but with `\varllim` used in place of `\varlim`.

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools}

\makeatletter\def\varllim@#1#2{%
\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
\hfil$#1\operator@font llim$\hfil\cr
\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#2\cr
\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\def\laxcolim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varllim@{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}
\def\laxlim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varllim@{\leftarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}

\begin{document}

\[ \varinjlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\alpha\,\beta}),\quad\varprojlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\beta\,\alpha}),\]%
\[ \laxcolim( E_{\alpha},f_{\alpha\,\beta}),\quad\laxlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\beta\,\alpha}),\]%
\end{document}​
```

I get an error saying that that `\varllim` is an undefined control sequence. I think I am missing something very basic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than reimplementing the whole thing, it's simpler to do a couple of patches:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\NewCommandCopy{\laxcolim}{\varinjlim}
\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy{\varllim@}{\varlim@}
\xpatchcmd{\laxcolim}{\varlim@}{\varllim@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varllim@}{lim}{llim}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\alpha\,\beta}),
\quad
\laxcolim( E_{\alpha},f_{\beta\,\alpha}),
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possible strategy:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\genericinjlim}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{{#1}{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}}}\nmlimits@
}
\def\varlim@#1#2{\varlim@@#1#2}
\def\varlim@@#1#2#3{%
  \vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
    \hfil$#1\operator@font #2$\hfil\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#3\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\varinjlim}{\genericinjlim{lim}}
\newcommand{\laxcolim}{\genericinjlim{llim}}

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\alpha\,\beta}),
\quad
\laxcolim( E_{\alpha},f_{\beta\,\alpha}),
\]

\end{document}
```

You can supplement this with

```
\newcommand{\genericprojlim}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{{#1}{\leftarrowfill@\textstyle}}}\nmlimits@
}
```

for projective limits.

In order to get better arrows, one can use `old-arrows`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\genericinjlim}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{{#1}{\varrightarrowfill@\textstyle}}}\nmlimits@
}
\newcommand{\genericprojlim}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{{#1}{\varleftarrowfill@\textstyle}}}\nmlimits@
}
\def\varrightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\varrightarrow}
\def\varleftarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\varleftarrow\relbar\relbar}

\def\varlim@#1#2{\varlim@@#1#2}
\def\varlim@@#1#2#3{%
  \vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
    \hfil$#1\operator@font #2$\hfil\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#3\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\varinjlim}{\genericinjlim{lim}}
\renewcommand{\varprojlim}{\genericprojlim{lim}}
\newcommand{\laxcolim}{\genericinjlim{llim}}

\newcommand{\elts}{\genericinjlim{\mathsf{elts}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\alpha\,\beta})
\quad
\laxcolim( E_{\alpha},f_{\beta\,\alpha})
\quad
\varprojlim( E_{\alpha},f_{\beta\,\alpha})
\quad
\elts(F)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using an older latex version which doesn't seem to support `\NewCommandCopy`, but the second solution works great for me. Thanks!

Comment: Your `old-arrows` solution is only relevant with Computer Modern. For other fonts, you might want to mention [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571261/19809) and [this update to it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587017/19809).